# Angular recapthca v3 token is not getting in server in local its working fine

Tags: angular, typescript

```
requestCaptchaToken(action) {
    console.log("Captcha starts 0===>");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.recaptchaV3Service.execute(action).subscribe((token) => {
        resolve(token);
        console.log('log', token)
      }, (err) => {
        console.log("err ============> ", err);
        this.toaster.show('Error', 'Something went wrong, Please try again later.', {
          status: 'danger',
          duration: 3000,
        });
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

in server its not getting the token. how could I proceed another step

Comment: For server you need to generate another recaptcha key as per your `url`. that `url` should be registered in recaptcha's account, then only you will get token in server.

Comment: here im using desktop application  by using electron .. here google capthca is not geeting